# can I run a package that is installed on the "client" project from my own project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdoc

I know this sounds like a weird question, let me try explaining it further with examples:

First of all, I'm trying to add some functionality to JSDoc in a simple library. Let's call it jsdoc-extra.

When a project includes my library, it should also have jsdoc installed. I have listed jsdoc as a dependency on my own library as well.

jsdoc-extra > package.json

```
{
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    [...]
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.6",
    [...]
  }
}
```

And let's suppose a "sample" project is trying to use my library (this is what I actually have running for now, installed from the file)

```
{
  [...]
  "dependencies": {
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.6",
    "jsdoc-cov": "file:../jsdoc-cov",
    "jsdoc-ts-utils": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

From my `jsdoc-extra` code I can search and find the `sample/node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js` that is installed on the "client" application (sample), or use my own `jsdoc-extra/node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc.js` instead when the first one is not available. I can then execute it with `spawn`

So far so good. However:

The "client" (sample project in this case) might be using some plugins on their jsdoc setup, like you can see in the previous code snippet, I have ts-utils installed as an example.

So when I'm inside the sample project, and try running:

```
node_modules/jsdoc/jsdoc-extra.js -c jsdoc.json
```

(jsdoc.json is the standard jsdoc config file that I just pass through to it)

I get this kind of errors:

```
(node:3961) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERROR: Unable to find the plugin "jsdoc-ts-utils"
```

It seems my app (jsdoc-extra) cannot use `jsdoc-ts-utils` that is installed on the client (sample) project, even when I run sample's own installed jsdoc.

I want to be able to execute it like this so the "client" project can execute `jsdoc-extra` without extra `jsdoc` configuration, it will use whatever it's already using for regular jsdoc operations.

I'm beginning to think that my best options is to actually write a jsdoc plugin...

I know this is a lot, and probably confusing, I'll gladly provide more info if you think it's necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to close this and instead just write a jsdoc plugin. It's the easier way to hack into the data it generates to do what I want. My extra functionality will be tied in with the doc generation, which is not ideal, but I'll deal with it...